# Can Python data structures, other than string, be passed using Format Specification Mini-Language?

Tags: python-3.x, format

When I define a custom formatting for a class, e.g.:

```
  def __format__(self, spec):
    match spec:
      case 'verbose':
        lines = np.where(self.shape[0], '8', '.').view(f'<U{self.shape[0].shape[-1]}').flat
        return f'\n{lines[0]}  id={self.id} color={self.color}, origin={self.pos}, area={self.area}\n' + '\n'.join(lines[1:])
      case 'terse':
        return f'{self.id}'
```

the `spec` parameter seems always to be a string. Is there a way to pass a non-string data structure inside `spec`? For example, a pair of strings?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about what you mean, but as far as I am aware, no, `spec` will always be a `str`, whatever string you put in the spec part of a format specification, i.e. `f"{<some expression>:<spec>}"` it's not clear to me how you would expect this to work exactly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga A pair of strings would work for my use case at hand.

Comment: And just to elaborate, a reason why it isn't clear what you are asking is because *you aren't passing anything to `__format__`, or rather, if you were, you could obviously pass whatever you want. e.g `MyClass().__format__(whatever_I_want)`, but this is a "dunder" method, it is a *hook*, the *runtime* provides the argument according to the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). So it really isn't clear *what you mean*

Comment: You aren't answering my question. I didn't ask for an example of a data structure (fwiw, a `str` is a data structure). When you say "Is there a way to pass", it isn't clear what you are talking about. This is a *hook*. It is used by various string formatting facilities in the language, so `"{0:<spec>}.format(MyClass())`  or with an f-string, `f"{MyClass():<spec>}"` ... what exactly are you proposing? In any case, as I stated, everything you write in `<spec>` will just be interpreted as a string. You *could* write something, then dynamically evaluate it or parse it or whatever

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't understand the terms you are using. In most programming languages, the route an argument takes from the function call site to function execution is termed *passing an argument*. What calling it a hook changes? If you insist, replace passing with hooking or whatever is appropriate for language lawyers.

Comment: My point is **you can pass whatever you want to that function**, `MyClass.__format__(whatever)`, Python certainly won't complain. But if you are defining `__format__`, then I *suspect* you are going to use it for the formatting utilities in the language, e.g. `str.format`, or f-strings. In *that case* **you** don't pass anything, the runtime does. It is out of your control, and the runtime is going to pass it a string. Always.

Comment: So, what would be helpful is if you provide a small, toy example with an example of how you *intend to use the class*, and what it would mean to pass something other than a string, how would that look like? `f"{MyClass():[1,2,3]}"`?

Comment: By *hook* I mean that the function will be used like a callback. So, suppose you have an API, `def frobnicate(value, callback)`, and the API of `frobnicate` indicates that the callback should be a function that takes a single paramter which will be passed a string. If you define some function, `def foo(x): ...` then *you can pass whatever you want to that function*, `foo(1)`, but the frobnicate API specifies precisely how it will call that callback, and it will always pass a string.

Comment: So, I think the answer to your quesiton is: the runtime will *always* pass a `str` to that argument, as specified in the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OK, `spec` is always a string. Thank you.